# Help needed to decide type of service account at SQL Server reporting services

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

My problem has to do with the kind of service account i need to setup in order to make reporting services on a sql server 2008 db work.The OS is windows server 2003.We need the reports to be viewed from users on the company intranet.this intranet is not on a domain, it is controlled from linux servers. The users will view the reports at the browser typing the url.
 My problem is that if i set the windows account as the service account,then every user will be prompted for the credential of the windows account and we don't want to give that kind of information to everyone. 
 What is the best way to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i'm understanding your question correctly, but if users are being prompted for credentials when they type the url, it is them that cant authenticate on the reports web server. Have your users got access into the virtual directory on the iis server?

Also in your reports, under the Data Sources option how are you authenticating on the database, if the users have direct access onto the database server Windows integrated security should work, otherwise you will need to save the connection authentication details into the report

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But we don't have IIS.the authentication for the database works (the db is set on the same server). my problem is that this is very unsafe.that's why i m searching for another option